# INSERT/UPDATE not working even with correct syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

***PROBLEM***:

I've written and been running a PHP script that previously had been working, and today I realize that although it appeared to be functioning correctly, for the past few days no data was being inserted or updated (basically any write queries). This does not trigger any errors, and when the exact same query is copy and pasted into a mysql terminal, it inserts correctly.

***CODE***

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `history` (`owner`, `user`, `status`, `now_date`)
VALUES ('{$owner['username']}', '{$user}', '1', NOW())";

if (!mysqli_query($db, $sql)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db)); }

echo "Affected rows: " . mysqli_affected_rows($db);
```

***RESPONSE***

```
Affected rows: 1
```

So it appears to be working, does not trigger any error, and when the same query is input into a mysql terminal, it works, it's just via PHP that it doesn't. Permissions for the user connecting is fine.

This problem has just happened in the last week, prior to that it was working perfectly. I'm really confused.

Thanks,
John.

Comment: @MayankVadiya No dont remove `{}` or it definitely wont work

Comment: print out the statement to see if you get the expacted result

Comment: Like I said, I have used the query that gets output with `die($sql);` and it inserts correctly, this is not a syntax issue.

Comment: when i was try its not working and getting same problem

Comment: What is the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY on the `history` table?

Comment: Try use Update set

UPDATE history
SET  (`owner`, `user`, `status`, `now_date`)
VALUES ('{$owner['username']}', '{$user}', '1', NOW())";

Comment: @RiggsFolly `id` is auto-increment and UNIQUE.

Comment: @MalithMcR I've amended from `REPLACE` to `INSERT`, the `REPLACE` was used with an older version of the script and isn't used anymore. The syntax is not the issue here, it inserts correctly when done via terminal/phpmyadmin, it's just via PHP that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You say that a column called `id` is the UNIQUE key of that table.

You are not using the `id` in that query, so how will it be able to know to do an INSERT or UPDATE(DELETE-INSERT) without the `id` field being there so it can make that decision.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a **PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index**, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

[**See the manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Comment: `REPLACE` was used with an older version of the script, I've since changed it to `INSERT` and it still does not work. I don't think this issue is query based, as the `INSERT` query works correctly in PhpMyAdmin. My gut tells me this is a server configuration issue somewhere, although no errors are being produced anywhere.

Comment: Sorry John. You cannot change your question once its been commented on and answered. That would make most question/answer session nonsence. Please ask another question if you have changed the basic premise